# Ansible deep merge hash array in vars

Tags: ansible

A want declare hash array in vars/main.yml or default/main.yml of some role, e.g.:

```
mysql:
  instances:
    new:
      port: 3306
      dir: /mydir
      config:
         innodb_log_file_size: '128M'
         tmp_table_size: '128M'
         innodb_buffer_pool_size: '10G'
         ...
```

And I want change only some values of keys in YAML inventory or group_vars. Other values must be taken from vars/main.yml of some role:

```
mysql:
  instances:
    new:
      config:
        innodb_buffer_pool_size: '2G'
```

I want result for used in jinja2 template:

```
mysql:
  instances:
    new:
      port: 3306
      dir: /mydir
      config:
         innodb_log_file_size: '128M'
         tmp_table_size: '128M'
         innodb_buffer_pool_size: '2G'
         ...
```

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/intro_configuration.html#hash-behaviour (merge) or https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries (combine filter)?

Comment: Why is it necessary to put all data into one dictionary? Just curious what use-case this might be.

Comment: I create service role so to speak, e.g.: nginx, mysql, pgsql....
In this role I describe the default settings, template configs.
Then I create a project role in which I can include the service role and I will be use most of default settings of specific service described in the service role. Only a small part of the service settings can be changed in the project role. 
And already in the project role, I can include various service roles, for example: nginx role + php-fpm role + supervisord role + role with some base RPM packages. I think it's very convenient

Answer (score 0):

> Question: *"Want to change only some values of keys in YAML inventory or group_vars. Other values must be taken from vars/main.yml of some role"*.
>
> 1) Service role (nginx, mysql, pgsql ...). In this role, I describe the default settings, ...
>
> 2) Then I create a project role in which I can include the service role and I will use most of the default settings described in the service role. Only a small part of the service settings can be changed in the project role.

Answer:

In the "service" roles create in *defaults* special variables for parameters that might be changed later. For example

```
mysql_port: "3306"
mysql_dir: "mydir"
mysql_innodb_log_file_size: "128M"
mysql:
  instances:
    new:
      port: "{{ mysql_port }}"
      dir: "{{ mysql_dir }}"
      config:
         innodb_log_file_size: "{{ mysql_innodb_log_file_size }}"
...
```

In the "project" role any variable with higher [precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) will override the role's defaults.